# PySpark/Glue: When using a date column as a partition key, its always converted into String?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am using PySpark on AWS Glue. It appears when writing a data set with date column used as partition key, its always converted into a string?

```
df = df \
  .withColumn("querydatetime", to_date(df["querydatetime"], DATE_FORMAT_STR))
...
df \
  .repartition("querydestinationplace", "querydatetime") \
  .write \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .partitionBy(["querydestinationplace", "querydatetime"]) \
  .parquet("s3://xxx/flights-test")
```

I notice my table DDL from Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `flights_test`(
  `key` string, 
  `agent` int, 
  `queryoutbounddate` date, 
  `queryinbounddate` date, 
  `price` decimal(10,2), 
  `outdeparture` timestamp, 
  `indeparture` timestamp, 
  `numberoutstops` int, 
  `out_is_holiday` boolean, 
  `out_is_longweekends` boolean, 
  `in_is_holiday` boolean, 
  `in_is_longweekends` boolean)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `querydestinationplace` string, 
  `querydatetime` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxx/flights-test/'
TBLPROPERTIES (...)
```

Notice

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `querydestinationplace` string, 
  `querydatetime` string)
```

Must the partition columns always be string? In fact `querydestinationplace` should be an int type. Will this string type be less efficient than an Int or Date?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known behavior of paquet. You can add the following line before reading the parquet file to omit this behavior:

```
# prevent casting the integer id fields, which are used for patitioning, 
# to be converted to integers.
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```

Comment: A follow up question is: is it better in general to use a date/int data type if I want to do things like BETWEEN queries. I assume its better?